# How can I resize a Composable horizontally based on drag in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a resizable composable. It should resize horizontally when the user drags it from it's handles.

I have a Clip class where I store it's start point and it's width:

```
data class Clip(
    var start: Float,
    var width: Float,
    var isDeleted: Boolean = false,
)
```

I've also created a DraggableClip composable that can be resized when its left or right handle is dragged. The resizing works well with the right handle, but I'm facing issues with the left handle. Instead of the left handle moving when dragged, the right one does.

[Here's a GIF demonstrating the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z33Bs.gif)

How can I make the left handle move and resize the clip's width correctly, so that dragging the left handle doesn't affect the position of the right handle?

Below is the code for my DraggableClip:

```
@Composable
fun DraggableClip(
    clip: Clip,
    maxWidth: Float,
    onDelete: () -> Unit,
    onDrag: (Float) -> Unit,
    clips: List<Clip>,
) {
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(clip.start) }

    var clipWidth by remember { mutableStateOf(clip.width) }
    var leftHandlePosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var rightHandlePosition by remember { mutableStateOf(clipWidth) }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset { IntOffset(clip.start.roundToInt(), 0) }
            .height(100.dp)
    ) {
        // Left Handle
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(10.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(Color.Gray)
                .let {
                    if (clip.isDeleted) it else {
                        it.draggable(
                            orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                            state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                                val proposedLeftPosition = leftHandlePosition + delta
                                val proposedWidth = clipWidth - delta

                                leftHandlePosition = proposedLeftPosition.coerceIn(0f, rightHandlePosition - 10f)
                                clipWidth = proposedWidth
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
        )

        // Main Draggable Clip
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(clipWidth.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(if (clip.isDeleted) Color.White else Color.Red)
                .let {
                    if (clip.isDeleted) it else it.draggable(
                        orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                        state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                            val proposedOffsetX = offsetX + delta

                            offsetX = proposedOffsetX.coerceIn(0f, maxWidth - clip.width)
                            onDrag(offsetX)
                        },
                    )
                }
        )

        // Right Handle
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(10.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(Color.Gray)
                .let {
                    if (clip.isDeleted) it else {
                        it.draggable(
                            orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                            state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                                val proposedRightPosition = rightHandlePosition + delta

                                rightHandlePosition = proposedRightPosition.coerceIn(leftHandlePosition + 10f, maxWidth)
                                clipWidth = rightHandlePosition - leftHandlePosition
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

And here's the composable I'm using for testing:

```
@Composable
fun DraggableClipRow() {
    val clip1 = Clip(0f, 150f)
    val clips = listOf(clip1)

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start
    ) {
        DraggableClip(
            clip = clip1,
            maxWidth = 500f,
            onDelete = {},
            onDrag = {},
            clips = clips
        )
    }
}
```